# Simple web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap data from [this site](https://www.forexcrunch.com/category/forex-weekly-outlook/gbp-usd-outlook/page/24/).

I want to create a `csv/excel` file scraping data from link.
At first, we need to extract the blog articles `title, date amd link` from the page ( in this page 11 article), then store in a file. Like this,

[image]

**My attempt:**

Here, Firstly, I tried to extract the blog links but there were also some unwanted link

```
import httplib2
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()

links =  []
 
status, response = http.request(f'https://www.forexcrunch.com/category/forex-weekly-outlook/gbp-usd-outlook/page/24/')




for link in BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser', parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):

      if 'gbp' in link['href'] :

        if link['href'] not in links:
          print(link['href'])
          links.append(link['href'])
```

From these links the blog article `containing weekly forecast need to be filtered`. Then, from link article date and title should retrieve and store them,

```
header = ['Year', 'Date', 'Title', 'Link']
f = open('summary.csv', 'w')
 
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(header)

for link in links :

      data = [Year,Date,Title,Article Link] # get link data and store
      writer.writerow(data)

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select all **parent** elements and after iterate each of them.
There are 2 types of articles, big one and 10 smallest.
There you have some example code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.forexcrunch.com/category/forex-weekly-outlook/gbp-usd-outlook/page/24/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

big_article = soup.find("div", class_='col-sm-12 col-md-6')
title = big_article.find("div", class_="post-detail").find("h5")
print("Title: " + title.text)
print("Link: " + title.find("a")["href"])
author_year = big_article.find("div", class_="post-author")
print("Author: " + author_year.find("a").text)
print("Date: " + author_year.find_all("li")[-1].text)
print("---------------------")

all_articles = soup.find_all("div", class_='col-sm-12 col-md-3')
for article in all_articles:
    title_author_link = article.find("div", class_="post-detail").find_all("a")
    print("Title: " + title_author_link[0].text)
    print("Link: " + title_author_link[0]["href"])
    print("Author: " + title_author_link[1].text)
    print("Date: " + article.find_all("li")[-1].text)
    print("---------------------")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Title: GBP/USD Forecast May 22-26
Link: https://www.forexcrunch.com/gbpusd-forecast-may-22-26/
Author: Kenny Fisher
Date: 5 years
---------------------
Title: GBP/USD Forecast May 15-19
Link: https://www.forexcrunch.com/gbpusd-forecast-may-15-19/
Author: Kenny Fisher
Date: 5 years
---------------------
```

I hope I have been able to help you.